# JOINing the tables to get null valued results

Tags: mysql

Here is my two tables `feeds` and `traders`. Now i want to select the rows from both tables where the `feed_id` of `feeds` table not in `trdr_feed_id` of `traders` table. And here is the structure of both tables.

**Feeds**

[image]

**Traders**

[image]

And this is the join query i'm using.

`SELECT * FROM feeds LEFT JOIN traders ON feeds.feed_id = traders.trdr_feed_id`

This is the output i'm getting. What i need is, only the rows with the null values. But please note that the columns with the null values should be preserved with the values null.

[image]

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this without `JOIN`

```
SELECT  Feed_ID
FROM    Feeds
WHERE   Feed_ID NOT IN
        (
            SELECT trdr_feed_id
            FROM    Traders
        )
```

or this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   Feeds a
          LEFT JOIN Traders b
              ON a.Feed_ID = b.trdr_feed_id
WHERE a.trdr_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT * 
FROM feeds 
     LEFT JOIN traders 
         ON IFNULL(feeds.feed_id, 0) = IFNULL(traders.trdr_feed_id, 0)
WHERE traders.trdr_feed_id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM feeds 
LEFT JOIN traders 
ON feeds.feed_id = traders.trdr_feed_id    
WHERE trdr_id IS NULL
```